# Dropdown toggle not working in bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

Its not working once I upgrade into Bootstrap 5.

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria- controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria- label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
```

Sample code: https://github.com/Devgroup-Asia/larablog/blob/main/resources/views/include/navbar.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria- controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria- label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
```

You may use this code. In bootstrap 5 data attribute works only if you use data-bs-{variable_name}.